Does lettuce support batch get commands through pipeline for redis in cluster mode?
I am using lettuce library and spring redis template for the redis commands, I am using executePipelined command for fetching multiple keys and the fields stored in hashkeys, do we need to use hastags even if we are using lettuce library, the risk here is that key may get un-evenly distributed if we use hastags for our keys.
Need an answer for this if anyone did this, we will do the testing for the same.

Assuming you have a sharded Redis cluster then some of the keys could end up on different shards. The Lettuce driver would handle this, but for the cost of additional network calls. So you'd need to choose between the possible additional network calls vs. the chance keys are distributed unevenly. Did I get your question right?
